# How can I properly iterate through items and put it in a new array in JavaScript in terms of performance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So this is my code:

```
let newArr = []

const items = [
    {
        name: 'JTB 0110-01',
        offers: ['one', 'two']
    },
    {
        name: 'LOBA CHEMIE',
        offers: ['three', 'four', 'five']
    },
    //more
]

items.forEach(item => {
    item.offers.forEach(i => newArr.push(i));
})

//more code
```

I want to loop over the items array and each offers property will be iterated and pushed to the new array.

For now the code is working, the problem though is before proceeding to the code under the `foreach`, I want the looping to be done already. How can I properly do this?

### Update

Sorry for not being clear. I want it to be synchronous like before going to the code after iteration, I want the looping to be done.

Comment: No idea what you mean by *"[...] before proceeding to the code under the foreach, I want the looping to be done already."*

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I mean before other code executes, I want every offer property pushed to the new array..

Comment: That's the way your code currently works. Are you under the impression that the callback to `forEach()` is executed asynchronously?

Comment: Three answers to this question already, but still clueless as to what the actual problem is.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Even better: _"Thank you, sir. Awesome and working."_ on an answer which does exactly the same as the code in the question just squeezed in an ES6-one-liner O.o

Comment: updated my post

Comment: _"I want it to be synchronous"_ Your code is...

Comment: All the answers here do the exact thing your code is **already** doing, in slightly different ways. Your code is *already synchronous*, `forEach` is **not asynchronous**, the iterations are already complete by the very next line of code.

Comment: Besides for the OP's already working code and regarding all the other proposed answers and being oblivious to the OP's  question's _"performance"_ part (as well as all the other answers), the most straightforward solution comes with picking [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) as the sole tool of choice ... `const newArr  = items.flatMap(({offers}) => offers)`. Performance should be considered when it becomes an issue. Readability and/or the correct tool for the task are more important.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and mapped array.

```js
var items = [{ name: 'JTB 0110-01', offers: ['one', 'two'] }, { name: 'LOBA CHEMIE', offers: ['three', 'four', 'five'] }],
    array = Array.prototype.concat(...items.map(({offers}) => offers));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: _"For now the code is working"_ So why should TO change its code?

Comment: That the TO has a wrong understanding of its code and that there is absolutely no need to change the code into a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spread` syntax in combination with `reduce` method.

The `reduce()` method applies a function against an **accumulator** and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a **single** value.

```js
const items = [ { name: 'JTB 0110-01', offers: ['one', 'two'] }, { name: 'LOBA CHEMIE', offers: ['three', 'four', 'five'] }]
let result = items.reduce(function(acc,elem){
  acc.push(...elem.offers);
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: _"For now the code is working"_ So why should TO change its code?

Answer (score -1):

You can use  `spread syntax` to combine the value of `offer` key

```js
let newArr = []

const items = [{
    name: 'JTB 0110-01',
    offers: ['one', 'two']
  },
  {
    name: 'LOBA CHEMIE',
    offers: ['three', 'four', 'five']
  }

]
var newArray = [];
items.forEach(function(item) {
  // // ... is spread syntax which will combine the array
   newArray.push(...item.offers)
})
console.log(newArray)
```